# How to get Cuda 7 working on Optimus technology under Linux.

Tags: nvidia

I am trying to install Cuda 7 on a Dell M3800 which has Optimus technology (Intel HD4600 + Nvidia Quadro K1100m). I am following the [instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#axzz3VymHOGZS) to the letter on fresh installs of Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 14.10, and OpenSUSE 13.2. I have tried .run and .deb / .rpm installs on all three.

In all package manager cases, Cuda 7 install works, but as soon as I reboot it bricks, before the login screen. I *think* it's at the ACPI daemon because if I boot into text mode it freezes there.

I can get Cuda 7 working if I use the .run installation (yes I blacklisted Nouveau as per the instructions), but in those cases I have to use a lightweight window manager (have tried i3 and LXDE) because hardware graphics acceleration becomes unavailable. Gnome 3 and Unity both fail, with Gnome on OpenSUSE crashing, and Unity freezing with no toolbar and no status bar (yes I tried all the usual ways of getting these back like reinitializing compiz etc - no luck).

So I can have Cuda 7 but then I lose graphics acceleration.

My Dell Precision M3800 is a 2014 machine which came with Windows pre-installed. Linux works perfectly on it if I don't install Cuda.

Does anybody know the specifics steps that I need to take to get Cuda 7 working with accelerated graphics on an Optimus-equipped notebook such as this one?

I am happy to disable Optimus and/or the Intel graphics if necessary as battery life is not very important to me. There is no such option in the bios of the machine.

Comment: Are you able to disable the Intel graphics from the BIOS? This would force Linux to use the Nvidia card. It could be that it's freaking out because it's trying to use the Nvidia drivers while the Intel graphics are active.

Comment: @Chris: sadly no. This is often an option on desktop computers with the HDxxxx setups but not on this particular notebook. I need somehow to bypass it or disable it in the OS.